# What are these small yellow bugs that are attacking my eggplant, and how can I stop them?

Tags: pest-control, pests, eggplant

Our Eggplant got infected by some yellow pests **(see image)**. 
[image: That yellow PEST stealing my Eggplant]
[image: Gotcha! Intruder ALERT]

---

Can anyone identify what they are? I try to avoid using pesticides whenever possible. What can be possible solutions to get rid of these pests without causing an environmental hazard? I reside in Lahore, Pakistan.

*The Eggplant says Thanks in advance.. !*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with BYJ's ID of the pest. Try neem oil concentrate, mixed appropriately, that should do the job - you'll probably need to spray every 14 days, otherwise, it's handpicking them all off, which whilst tedious, is certainly the most organic way to go.

Comment: Or if there isn't any fruit, they *could* use a chemical. How strange, I've not seen them eat anything but beans before.

Comment: Someone told me that spraying soap water also gets rid of pests? Has anyone had any experience of that?

Comment: @haanimasood Yes, there are insecticidal soaps you can spray, but they're so close to herbicidal soaps that they often damage plants. I usually use neem oil, as Bamboo recommended.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like *Epilachna varivestis* Mulsant (Mexican bean beetle larva) from *Coccinellidae* family.

[image: Epilachna varivestis - USDA]

> **Cultural Control:** Cultural control efforts may include destruction of overwintering locations and late planting of the soybean crop. The
> destruction of overwintering locations increases exposure to inclement
> weather conditions and can greatly reduce adult numbers the following
> spring. Under certain conditions, a combination of a trap crop with
> delayed planting of a portion of the field might be used to advantage.
> Since overwintering beetles actively forage upon emergence in the
> spring, beans planted early will attract a disproportionate number of
> beetles feeding during their preoviposition period.
>
> **Biological Control:** Natural control organisms include at least 17 species of predators. They feed on bean beetle eggs, larvae and pupae.
> The beetles are protected by hard wing covers and by an offensive,
> yellow liquid which is secreted in small drops from the leg joints
> when the insects are disturbed. Ten species of parasitoids are prevalent in soybeans
> during the vegetative stages, but only the tachinid fly Paradexodes
> epilachnae and the eulophid wasp Pediobius foveolatus seem to be
> promising in reducing the number of bean beetles. Because P.
> epilachnae is not native, it is necessary to import it when the
> Mexican bean beetle is an important pest. P. foveolatus is a
> parasitoid of epilachnine beetles from India. It parasitizes Mexican
> bean beetle larvae during the growing season, but fails to overwinter
> for lack of diapause capability and/or available host material. The
> annual inoculative releases of this insect, if conducted early enough
> and in conjunction with establishment of nurse plot areas of snap
> beans in a widespread manner, are capable of suppression of the
> Mexican bean beetle on soybeans.
>
> **Insecticides:** For curative control in outbreak circumstances, several insecticides are currently available. Selection of an
> appropriate insecticide and timing of its application are very
> important. Studies of residual efficacy have dealt primarily with
> soil-applied insecticides for Mexican bean beetle control. Certain
> systemic insecticides can provide control for 70 days when applied at
> planting or as a side-dress treatment during midseason cultivation;
> these materials only provide control for half a season. The foliar
> insecticides suppress Mexican bean beetle larvae for up to two weeks
> posttreatment in garden beans and soybeans.

***Reference:*** [University of Florida](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/bean/mexican_bean_beetle.htm)

---

Quoted website talks about this pest in other plant species, but the tips can also be applied to *Solanum melongena* L. About biological control I can say that where I live we do not suffer this pest, in fact we use other species of the family Coccinellidae to combat aphids (and I know by experience that *Podisus* spp. may reduce population of Anatis ocellata L.).